# transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo and ComplicationController

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, clockkit

I'm looking to send data to my complication as part of a `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to update the data displayed but there seems to be little documentation from Apple on how to setup the relationship between this and the complication itself.

When a `ComplicationController` is created, am I supposed to create a `WCSession` as well and begin listening for the delegate calls? I'm managed to place it into `getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication` and this seems to work when the iOS application is running but *not* when the app has been killed (or no longer running).

I'm curious if anyone has a good guide for getting data to the watch as part of a remote JSON push notification when the iOS app is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend watching the [WatchConnectivity session from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-713/) as it covers updating complications quite a bit towards the end.

In summary, in the iOS app once you have the contents to send:

```
    NSDictionary *userInfo = // data to send
    [[WCSession defaultSession] transferComplicationUserInfo:userInfo];
...
- (void)session:(WCSession * __nonnull)session didFinishUserInfoTransfer:(WCSessionUserInfoTransfer *)userInfoTransfer error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    // handle error
    NSLog(@"%s %@ (%@)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, userInfoTransfer, error);
}
```

and on the watch side:

```
@property WCSession *session;
...
    _session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    _session.delegate = self;
    [_session activateSession];
...
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo {
   // persist data and trigger reload/extend of complication(s)
}
```

Comment: How would you access the `didReceiveUserInfo` data easiest from the `ComplicationController`? My `didReceiveUserInfo` is in my `InterfaceController`.  So does `didReceiveUserInfo` need to go in both `InterfaceController` and `ComplicationController`, or is there some easier/better way to access the data from `ComplicationController`?  I assume there's gotta be, but thats what I'm trying to figure out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190685/watchkit-complication-get-complication-data-from-extension-delegate

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? i can't get my complication to update at all